# Has anyone tried to implement a Haskell-like case-of statement in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, haskell

I'm wondering if anyone knows of an implementation (or attempted implementation) of this.

**In Haskell**

Haskell has an expression that performs case distinction via pattern matching:

```hs
let a = [1,2,3] in
let is_empty = case a of
      [] -> True
      (_:_) -> False in
-- Note: is_empty == False
...
```

**In C++**

C++ overload resolution does something similar to pattern matching.  One can always define an overload set to do case distinction on types, but in many cases it would be more convenient to use expressions.

I can see how this could *almost* work in C++14:

```
template<typename Head, typename Tail>
using Cons = boost::tuples::cons<Head, Tail>;
using Nil = boost::tuples::null_type;

template<typename Tuple>
bool is_empty(Tuple const & tuple)
{
  return case_of(tuple)(
      [](Cons<auto,auto> const &) { return false; }
    , [](Nil) { return true; }
    );
}
```

But I don't think `Cons<auto,auto>` (or anything like it) is valid in any version of C++.  We have generic lambdas, but in this case I want to do template argument deduction in a lambda.

So, is there anything like this case_of out in the wild?  Or does anyone know of a failed attempt at one?

Or can you see how to achieve the pattern-match I'm going for?  It has to be entirely contained in an expression.

Comment: If `boost::tuples::cons` is template (as you use it like one later), you should use `template <...> using` instead. Also, what does `case_of` do? How is it implemented?

Comment: Thanks.  I fixed the declaration of Cons.  The question is exactly whether someone has tried to implement something like case_of.  From the armchair, it seems plausible that given a list of arguments and a list of functions, some metaprogramming could be used to call the correct one, or raise an error if the call is ambiguous.

Comment: From what I know lambdas can't be used in SFINAE like that. The point is, the expression must be valid when function is called, so if only one case matches, other cases must be invalid then - and if they are invalid the error is raised. You could achieve this functionality with templates and classic SFINAE, but I doubt someone will come up with in-scope definition of such things like you want to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was one article on russian *Habrahabr* web site last year about some kind of pattern matching in C++. It allows you to match over types (yeah, more like *type matching*) or even on some boolean compile-time conditionals. It looks like this:

```
template<class T>
decltype(auto) test(T& value) {
    return match(value
        ,[](std::string value)    { cout << "This is string"; return value + " Hi!"; }
        ,[](int i)                { cout << "This is int";    return i * 100; }
        ,[](auto a)               { cout << "This is default";return nullptr; }
    );
}

match(true_type{}
         ,[](bool_constant< T::value == 10 >)                        { cout << "1" ; }
         ,[](bool_constant< (T::value == 20 && sizeof...(Args)>4) >) { cout << "2" ; }
    );
```

You can find more code snippets and details of implementation in [blog post itself](https://habrahabr.ru/post/282630/). This blog-post is inspired by this C++ [Mach7](https://github.com/solodon4/Mach7) library which is rather ugly by blog post author opinion in some places but allows you to write something like this:

```
// Fibonacci numbers
int fib(int n)
{
    var<int> m;

    Match(n)
    {
      Case(1)     return 1;
      Case(2)     return 1;
      Case(2*m)   return sqr(fib(m+1)) - sqr(fib(m-1));
      Case(2*m+1) return sqr(fib(m+1)) + sqr(fib(m));
    }
    EndMatch
}
```

But dunno about lists. You can probably look for other answers and/or implement your custom list matcher.

Comment: Thanks.  This certainly answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of struct SFINAE here.

```
template<class tuple, class = void>
struct is_empty : std::false_type
{ };

template<class Tuple>
struct is_empty<
    Tuple, 
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_base_of<Nil, Tuple>::value, void
    >
> : std::true_type
{ };
```

But remember that works for type, not for variable. But since tuples can't change size in C++, making a function doesn't give us much. But if you wanted one, then:

```
template<class Tuple>
constexpr bool isEmpty(const Tuple&) {
    return is_empty<Tuple>::value;
}
```

So this code:

```
boost::tuple<> t1;
std::cout << isEmpty(t1) << std::endl;

boost::tuple<int, float> t2;
std::cout << isEmpty(t2) << std::endl;
```

Results in output:

```
1
0
```

But these structures have to be defined outside functions.

Comment: I think the closest analog to my example using out-of-line functions would be:

    `bool is_empty(Nil) { return true; }
    template<typename Head, typename Tail>
    bool is_empty(Cons<Head, Tail> const &) { return false; }`